# Trouble sorting custom objects in an NSArray numerically

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting, nsarray

If I'm trying to sort `BL_Player` by their `playerScore` property:

```
NSArray *sortedPlayers = [players sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(BL_Player *a1, BL_Player *a2) {
                                 return [a1.playerScore compare:a2.playerScore options:NSNumericSearch];
```

OR

```
NSArray *sortedPlayers = [players sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
                                     NSInteger first = [(BL_Player *)a playerScore];
                                     NSInteger second = [(BL_Player *)b playerScore];
                                     return [first compare:second options:NSNumericSearch];
                                 }];
```

both of which return bad receiver types. What's wrong with doing comparisons on ints or NSInteger?

Comment: compare method works for NSNumber not for int or NSInteger

Comment: ... so with any sane compiler settings, this should never have compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
NSArray *sortedPlayers = [players sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(BL_Player *a1, BL_Player *a2) {

    if (a1.playerScore > a2.playerScore) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } 
    else if (a1.playerScore < a2.playerScore) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    else
       return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

Change as per your requirement.

May help you.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. I realize now that you cannot run compare across ints.

Comment: I modified it to use 'else' instead of 'else if' because of the block.

Comment: @Macness , you should not do this, better to use the updated one.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to do this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"playerScore"
                                              ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [players sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

for descending order change YES to NO.

Comment: Just curious, how is using a descriptor better than a block?

Comment: this is better because you need not to worry about the type playerScode whether it is NSNumber, NSInteger, int or something else and also doesn't require you to write your own comparator.

Comment: It's also several times slower. And a lot less flexible.